# How to re-throw a series of events when the last event in the series runs in A-Frame?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, aframe

I have a series of events that run when a box is clicked. I want the series to continuously re-run when the last event in the series is finished executing. Below is the event series that is running. When colorSwit1 is finished running, I want the entire sequence to start over again.

```
event-set__colorSwit9="_target: #signalLight9; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:0"
                           event-set__colorSwit8="_target: #signalLight8; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:20"
                           event-set__colorSwit7="_target: #signalLight7; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:40"
                           event-set__colorSwit6="_target: #signalLight6; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:60"
                           event-set__colorSwit5="_target: #signalLight5; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:80"
                           event-set__colorSwit4="_target: #signalLight4; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:100"
                           event-set__colorSwit3="_target: #signalLight3; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:120"
                           event-set__colorSwit2="_target: #signalLight2; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:140"
                           event-set__colorSwit1="_target: #signalLight1; _event:click; animation.property: color; animation.from:#FFFFFF; animation.to:#AA0000; animation.dur:20; animation.delay:160"
```

I tried playing around with the A-Frame component but I did not have much luck re-triggering the series of events. See below for the A-Frame component.

```
<!--Loop the right turn  -->
<script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('reTrigger', {
        init: function () {
            this.el.addEventListener('click', function (colorSwit1) {
            this.el.emit('colorSwit9')
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that events are properly emitted and listened to? I see a click listener, and not a [custom event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Comment: The event is triggered when I click ab object, but it runs only one time.

Comment: What event should it listen to? It does not respond to more clicks because you click it only once. Have the last event emit a custom event, and listen for that.

Comment: Okay ill try that thank you.